# Search and remove algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, opencv

Say you have an ordered array of values representing x coordinates.

`[0,25,50,60,75,100]`

You might notice that without the 60, the values would be evenly spaced (25). This would be indicative of a repeating pattern, something that I need to extract using this list (regardless of the length and the values of the list). In this ***particular*** example, the algorithm should find and remove the 60.

There are no time or space complexity requirements.

Both the values in the list and the ideal spacing (e.g 25) are unknown. So the algorithm must obtain this by looking at the values. In addition, the number of values, and where the outliers are in the array are not guaranteed. There may be more than one outlier. The algorithm should return a list with the outliers removed. Extra points if the algorithm uses a threshold for the spacing.

Edit: Here is an example image[image]

Here there is one outlier on the x axis. (green-line) There are two on the y axis. The x-coordinates of the array represent the rho of the line on that axis.

Comment: Interesting problem, in particular if the list is just `[50,60,75,100]`, where each delta appears exactly once, and there's still a clear "outlier" in the sequence. The answers so far provided won't help here.

Comment: it's looking like there must be some supplementing criteria for making the cut

Comment: I guess in the general case those solutions still work well, assuming the number of outliers is small compared to the total number of values.

Comment: More information about a valid result as well as the nature and size of the result would be helpful. Does it need to be optimal? Does it need to keep a certain amount of elements (and how is that amount defined)? Does it need to return just one list or a choice of possible lists? How many elements in a typical list? How fast and space-efficient should it be?

Comment: I updated the question to include more information. I attempted to leave it vague at first. I don't want to ward off any abstract approaches.

Comment: @tobias_k the number of outliers is usually less than the number of values. They are all coordinates for lines drawn onto an image. Pattern detection of sorts.

Comment: @JoshSharkey If they are points for a line, shouldn't those then be tuples, or two lists? And shouldn't a list with one outlier actually rather be `[25, 50, 60, 100]` instead of `[25, 50, 60, 75, 100]`, i.e. the outlier replacing a point, instead of "shifting" all the later points by one posiiton?

Comment: I've simplified the question because I can get the x coordinates from the tuples easily. These tuples are all just horizontal lines represented by `(rho, theta=90)` the only important part here are the x coordinates (I think, haha). The number of lines, and the amount of those lines that are outliers can vary. I'm wondering if there is a mathematical approach to consistently getting the desired, pattern-indicating lines each time. (knowing that they are equally spaced).

Comment: The pattern detection sounds interesting. Could you share a visual example of what the lines and outliers look like in relation to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
arr = [0,25,50,60,75,100]
```

First construct the distances array

```py
dist = np.array([arr[i+1] - arr[i] for (i, _) in enumerate(arr) if i < len(arr)-1])
print(dist)
>> [25 25 10 15 25]
```

Now I'm using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [np.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to cut the array in 3 part: the main , the upper values and the lower values. I arbitrary set them to 5%.

```py
cond_sup = np.where(dist > np.percentile(dist, 95))
print(cond_sup)
>> (array([]),)
cond_inf = np.where(dist < np.percentile(dist, 5))
print(cond_inf)
>> (array([2]),)
```

You now got indexes where the value is different from the others.

So, `dist[2]` has a problem, which mean by construction the problem is between `arr[2]` and `arr[2+1]`

Comment: I got some good takeaways from this approach! but this will lead to me isolating 60 and 75, where only 60 is the culprit. This won't be an accepted solution.

Comment: Just look at dist[2-1] and dist[2+1] to know which one is an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to remove 1 or more numbers from this array. So I think the way to solve this problem will be like this:
`array A[] = [0,25,50,60,75,100];`

- sort array (if needed).
- create a new array `B[]` with value `i-th: B[i] = A[i+1] - A[i]`
- find the value of `B[]` elements that appear most time. It's will be our distance.
- find `i` such that `A[i+1]-A[i] != distance`
- find `k (k>i and k min)` such that `A[i+k]-A[i] == distance`
- so, we need remove `A[i+1] => A[i+k-1]`
  I hope it is right.